# Styled-Components TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useDebugValue')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I installed styled-component on my Next.js project using `yarn add` and used `styled.div` to export a styled component, but when I try to render it, it throws this error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useDebugValue')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useDebugValue')
    at Object.useDebugValue (C:\Users\project\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1657:23)
    at C:\Users\project\node_modules\styled-components\dist\styled-components.cjs.js:1:18285
    at Object.I [as render] (C:\Users\project\node_modules\styled-components\dist\styled-components.cjs.js:1:19230)
```

Can someone please explain what might have caused this to happen and how to fix it? Thank you

I tried deleting the whole node_modules folder and reinstalling all the packages and dependencies, as well as tried to check if all the packages are of the latest version. I also checked the type of all the variables and components I use and they are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem.

In the documentation of styled components you can see the proper way to use it. Here is an example:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.section`
  padding: 4rem;
  background: red;
`;

// Use Wrapper like any other React component – except they're styled!
render(
  <Wrapper>
    Hello World!
  </Wrapper>
);
```

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#getting-started